# Python: Threading Exception

Tags: python

New to python and recently running into issues getting data from yfinance when running:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

data = yf.download('MSFT', start='2020-01-01', end="2020-02-01")['Adj Close']
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ctb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/ctb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/ctb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/multitasking/__init__.py", line 104, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ctb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 169, in _download_one_threaded
    data = _download_one(ticker, start, end, auto_adjust, back_adjust,
  File "/Users/ctb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 181, in _download_one
    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
  File "/Users/ctb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 247, in history
    df.index = df.index.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'
```

Any direction on how to resolve is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a known issue with yfinance and pandas.
Consider downgrading pandas to 1.3.5 or older.

```
pip install pandas==1.3.5
```

Comment: Thank you.  downgrading pandas to 1.3.5 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

there is something called `df`, this `df` has data attribute `index` and within this `index`'s namespace there is no attribute called as `tz_localize`, so when you try to get this `df.index.tz_localize ...` you get an error.